pug/uikit nav sidebar lost left padding after uikit upgrade
I forked from this https://github.com/chekromul/uikit-ecommerce-template
to build a static github page.
but after I upgrade uikit to latest version, the side navbar lost its left paddings.
before I upgrade uikit

after:

no code changes, only differece is uikit version.
src file path is src/templates/layouts/_informational.pug
and the code is here:
    aside(class="uk-width-1-4 uk-visible@m tm-aside-column")
  section(class="uk-card " +
                "uk-card-default " +
                "uk-card-small"
          uk-sticky="offset: 90; bottom: true;")
    div.uk-container.uk-container-expand
      nav
        ul.uk-nav.uk-nav-default.tm-nav
          each item in informationalNav
            li(class= {"uk-active": item.id == informationalActivePage})
              a(href= item.href)= item.title

i also found this thread,
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/4648
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/4638
as per my understanding, there is a new way to apply the nav horizontal padding, it's using the nav-container instead, but as I tried a few times, it's still not working.
one of the codes that i tried:
    aside(class="uk-width-1-4 uk-visible@m tm-aside-column")
  section(class="uk-card " +
                "uk-card-default " +
                "uk-card-small"
          uk-sticky="offset: 90; bottom: true;")
      **div.uk-container.uk-container-expand**
        nav
          ul.uk-nav.uk-nav-default.tm-nav
            each item in informationalNav
              li(class= {"uk-active": item.id == informationalActivePage})
                a(href= item.href)= item.title

